# install conda package from URL

Tags: python, conda

In conda,
is there a way to install package directly from URL as below ;

```
conda install --url https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytest/3.4.0/download/linux-64/pytest-3.4.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
```

Comment: What is wrong with doing this `conda install -c conda-forge pytest` out of interest?

Comment: noarch is used by default + cannot identify the correct build for python

Comment: How do you know it identifies the wrong build for Python? What error message do you get?

Answer (score 6):

You can install packages given urls by first adding the urls to a file (one per line) and calling `conda install` with the `--file` flag.

**Example**

To install a specific numpy package: Create a file called `my_packges.txt` and add the following lines

```
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/numpy-base-1.14.5-py36h2b20989_4.tar.bz2 
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/numpy-1.14.5-py36h2aefc1b_4.tar.bz2
```

Call conda install:

`conda install --file my_packages.txt`

**Note:** I understand this is a bit of a hack, but I know no other way of doing it, and in my experience it works without any nasty side-effects.

**Edit 1/15/2019:** It also appears that you can simply call:
`conda install <url>`

Comment: There are some nasty effects:
   conda depency depends on the order of the list of packages...
   it may have some conflicts.

Comment: Interesting. I did notice that conda skips the "solving environment" step in the logs - so it does seem to be a less controlled way of adding packages.

Comment: Anyone knows how to do the equivalent of this with a conda env file (yml)?