# How to install from specific url with conda env file (yml)

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

Anyone out there knows how to install a **conda** package (not pip) from a specific url with a conda env file (yml)?

Example: :

```
name: special_env

channels:
  - defaults

dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - pip=21.2.4
  - https://special_place.com/special/special_conda_pack.tar-01.2.03-0.bz2 <--- I want something like that.
```

(*https://special_place.com/special/special_conda_pack-01.2.03-0.tar.bz2* is only use as example this is not my real url)

I tried something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54084615/6210975 and many other attempts by playing with channels without success.

**NOTE1:** I am able to install my package with `conda install https://special_place.com/special/special_conda_pack-01.2.03-0.tar.bz2`

**NOTE2**
Also tried this approach:

Since `conda install https://special_place.com/special/special_conda_pack.tar.bz2` is working. I  I thought I could simply create a test env and then export it with `conda env export > env_with_resolved_url.yml`

```
name: env_with_resolved_url
channels:
  - https://special_place.com/special/...       <--- Resolved url

dependencies:
  - ...
  - special_conda_pack=01.2.03=0                <--- Resolved versioning format
  - ...

prefix: /.../miniconda3/envs/env_with_resolved_url
```

However when I try to recreate this env from file I get UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid. (error code: 404)

Comment: Is the URL organized like a conda channel (as described [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html)?

Comment: No i am in a context where there is no repodata.json

Answer (score 0):

This ain't my prefered option but it does the trick. Basically I create a custom channel with the manually downloaded package (see
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html for more details) and then I use it in my env file (yml) or my config file (.condarc):

```
channels:
  - ...
  - file:///path_to_custom_local_channel_using_downloaded_bz2
  - ...
```

In your env file (.yml) don't forget to use versioning properly. For example for *special_conda_pack.tar-01.2.03-0.bz2* you need to use:

```
dependencies:
  - ...
  - special_conda_pack=01.2.03=0                <--- Resolved versioning format
  - ...
```